# Call Blocking & identification Enable Error Callkit

Tags: ios, callkit

I added call kit feature in my app. It was worked previously. But I added swift code to objective c call kit extension. I am getting an error when I am enabling the extension.

Here is the device log:

```
error   14:42:48.454469 +0300   com.apple.CallKit.CallDirectory Error loading extension data: Error Domain=CallDirectoryHandler Code=2
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Use the debugger to trace the initialisation of your extension and see what is going wrong. You can also look in the device console log

Comment: I added device log.@Paulw11

Comment: Code 2 is "loading interrupted". This basically means the extension crashed or was terminated. You will need to try and find more information; attach the debugger to your extension and see what happens or look for more information in the log. Extensions have much lower memory quotas and can be terminated if they exceed it, for example. Showing some code may also help.